# Javascript: What is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript

```
  <html>
   <head>
    <script>
 var play;
 var target;
 var count = 0;
 var guess;
 var colors = ["blue ", "coral ", "orchid ", "red ", "cyan ", "dark orange", "aqua ", "yellow ", "gold ", "brown "];

 var colors = colors.sort();

 function do_this() {
   var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length));
   target = colors[choose];
   alert("The correct answer is " + target);
   alert(typeof(colors));
   while (true) {
     play = prompt("I am thinking one of these colors\n\n" + colors + "What color am I thinking of?");
     guess = colors.indexOf(play);

     count = count + 1;
     if (guess == -1) {
       alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color");
       continue;
     }
     if (guess > target) {
       alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct\n\n" + "Hint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine\n\n Please try again");
       continue;
     }
     if (guess < target) {
       alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct\n\n" + "Hint: your color is alphabetically lower than mine\n\n Please try again");
       continue;
     }
     alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color\n\n!" + "It took you" + count + "guesses to finish the game\n\n" +
       "You can see the color of the background");
     return true;
   }
 }

    </script>
    <body onload = "do_this()">
    </body>
    </head>
    </html>
```

When I try to run even if I enter correct color it shows that "Sorry, I don't recognize your color", when I tried to check what value it is taking in guess it is showing -1. Please help!

Comment: It does work, when you enter space after color name in a prompt

Answer (score 1):

`var colors = ["blue ", "coral ", "orchid ", "red ", "cyan ", "dark orange", "aqua ","yellow ", "gold ", "brown "];4`

Each word has a space after it. Remove the space and it will work. Also whats with the 4? You can remove that too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing space inside of the double quotes behind each color name. If you remove the spaces you should be good to go.